# High paging and memory consumption in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, memory

This is my first question about SQL Server, I'm new to SQL Server and I don't understand few things, so hope you can help me.

We got a SQL Server 2008 with 2 instances and also with Analysys Services installed (on same box).

The server is:

> 2 Quad core Xeon
>
> 80GB RAM

The SQL Server instances are configured by default, but we got times where memory consumption is high and also high pagination is presented, does this means that the memory is incorrectly configured?

Do I need to make changes in the configuration?

Actually, I'm starting to administer SQL Server, so I don't understand many things, any help or document is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the MAX server memory settings configured on the instances ?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Have you configured max server memory for both instances ? Can you please add relevant paging information(message) into question so that we have logs with us. Also run `select @@version` on both instances and add the output in your question. Please add as much information as you can so that we can provide you correct answer.